# Minimum in bitonic array with plateaus

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, binary-search

I'm trying to find minimum in array which has this kind of structure in general:
[image]

Array consists of non-negative integers [0; 1e5-1]. It may contain any number of such steps, be sorted or just a constant. I want to find it in *O(logn)* thats why I'm using binary search. This code handle all cases except cases there is any plateau:

```
size_t left = 0, right = arr.size() - 1;
while (left < right) {
    const size_t mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
    if ((mid == 0 || arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1]) && (mid + 1 == size || arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1])) {
        return mid;
    }
    if (arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1] || arr[mid] > arr[right]) {
        left = mid + 1;
    }
    else {
        right = mid;
    }
}
return left;
```

Example of bad input: [4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2].

Unfortenatly, I'm out of ideas how to fix this cases. Maybe it's even impossible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible to do in `log n` time in general.

1. Assume an array of `n` elements equal to `1` and a single element of `0`.
2. Your problem now reduces into finding that `0` element.
3. By "visiting" (=indexing) any member `1` you gain no knowledge about position of `0` - making the search order irrelevant.
4. Therefore you have to visit every element to find where the `0` is.

If you really want, I think the following algorithm should be roughly `O(log n + #elements-on-plateaus)`

1. Set `left, right` as for binary search
2. Compute `middle`.
3. Go left from `middle` until:

   - If you find a decrease, set `right=pos` where `pos` is the decreased element and go 4.
   - If you find an increase, set `left=pos` where `pos` is the increased element and go 4.
   - If you reach `left` position, go right from `middle` instead and do the analogous actions.

     - [X] If you reach `right` too, you are on a plateau and range `[left,right]` are the minimal elements of the array.
4. Repeat until you hit [X].

Comment: @Egor No problem, maybe check whether `pos` should be the increased/deacreased element or the one before that. Not sure about these +-1 issues... Also careful about treating `right` as exclusive and `left` as inclusive bound of the range.